# Matomo doesn't track actions anymore

Tags: matomo, custom-dimensions

I am currently trying to improve my matomo skills.
I created Custom Dimensions and started tracking them like this:

```
    _paq.push(['setCustomDimension',1,kategorie]);
    _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
```

It worked.
After that I created a Goal and tried to create my own Plugin.

Now my Custom Dimensions suddenly aren't tracked anymore - Matomo shows me there are 0 Actions in the Visits, though I did several Actions.

I thought I might have destroyed something while creating my Plugin etc. so I deleted it, but my Custom Dimensions still aren't tracked.

Do you have any idea what my Problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

How were you checking that tracking dimensions worked before? You mean data being in the reports or just parameter being added in the GET request?

First of all, check your Visitors/Visitor log report - the lack of those numbers in the summaries may be effect of archiving not being run in the meantime.

I'm not sure how creating a Plugin could relate to this, maybe you can tell more what you mean here?

What is always a good idea is running debug mode on the request, so you can get confirmation if dimension value is picked up properly. Sometimes it maybe issue of it's length - afaik custom dimension value is limited to 250 chars.

Comment: I was able to see data in my report before. Now I can't see data in my report, I can't see the custom dimensions being tracked in the visitor log and I can't see the custom dimension data in the log_link_visit_action table in my database anymore.

I just had the same problem in a new matomo installation, although I didn't change anything except adding more custom dimensions.